# Convert array string into an array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've saved some users ids in the database like this:

```
column user_ids: [2,1]
```

When I show column's value is `"[2,1]"`

How can I convert this to an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a valid Json string. You can use json_decode to get the array.

`json_decode("[2,1]");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
<?php
$string = "[2,1]";
$result = json_decode($string);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```